# Some facebook pages have 0 like count in the like button widget

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Steps I am trying to do:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/
2. Fill in my facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/KockaNeniPes/
3. The widget is generated, but with 0 likes

You can check, that the page has around 3000 likes.

I tried other facebook pages and it works fine for them.
Another example of a facebook page which does not receive correct like count: "onesipcoffee" (also 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confirmed facebook issue, hope they will fix it soon
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1813975232186394/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/426149314385861/